# Understanding a question asked about "consumption possibilities"

Tags: markets

I am studying business finance for my MBA. I am a software engineer, and am finding some basic concepts really difficult. I believe I may be overthinking it. This is not for an assignment, it's a question from a book. I am not after "the answer", I am more after a better understanding of the topic "consumption possibilities with and without the capital market". I am also after actually understanding this question. I am comfortable with calculus and advanced maths... and I am simply failing to understand even the actual *meaning* of what is being asked.

The question:

> "Assume a three-date model in which a rational person has an endowment of $2000 now, $1000 in Year 1 and $500 in Year 2. If the person wants to consume $400 now and $1200 in year 2, what could she consume in Year 1 if (1) there is no capital market? (2) There is a capital market with an interest of 5% per year"

I realise that with a capital market $100 today will become $105 in a year (doh). But... from the question it looks like this fictional person is spending $1000 in year 1 (as they went from $2000 to $1000), and then spent another $500 in year 2 (since they are left with $500). So my understanding is that this person has $2000, and after two years is left with $500. Or maybe here "endowment" is how much they earn?

But then the question says "If the person wants to consume $400 now and $1200 in year 2" -- then I am lost. Is that $400 and $1200 on *top* of what they have just spent?

Or am I overthinking it?

I am not even going to start with "what if there is a financial market with a 5% interest", since I don't even really understand the question.

Help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oxford Dictionaries:

> endowment: an income or form of property given or bequeathed to someone.

The question could probably be phrased better but they way I read it

> Assume a three-date model in which a rational person has an endowment of $2000 now, $1000 in Year 1 and $500 in Year 2.

simply means they receive three cashflows of 2000, 1000, and 500, respectively.

> If the person wants to consume $400 now and $1200 in year 2, what could she consume in Year 1 if (1) there is no capital market?

i.e. no interest earned/discounted present value, so (2000 - 400) + (1000 - x) + (500 - 1200) >= 0

> (2) There is a capital market with an interest of 5% per year

[(2000 - 400) * 1.05 + (1000 - x)] * 1.05 + 500 - 1200

Sometimes it helps to draw the timeline with the positive/negative cashflows at each point in time T.

Comment: The most beautiful answer I could possibly hope for

Comment: I don't understand the downvote to the question... oh well.